# How should I stop strings that are numbers from rounding when displayed?

Tags: java, android, database, string, listview

in my app I am displaying number strings and noticed that "7.000444" displays as "7.00044". In addition, "0.567567" displays as "0.56757". Finally, adding any non number part(ie a letter) makes them display with the full number followed by the other key. Is there a way to stop the behaviour of the first two? I am displaying them by adding that to a database which is then displayed in a ListView. The code for creating the string is a set of buttons, for the buttons 0-9 it is:

```
Button one;
one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            working = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
            now = working.toString();
            total1 = total.concat(now);
            equation1 = equation.concat(now);
            equation = equation1;
            total = total1;
            if(b){mnDbHelper.updateNote(equation, mnDbHelper.testCount());}
            else{mnDbHelper.createNote(equation);
            b=true;}
            fillData();
        }
});
```

With the 1 being changed as necessary.
The decimal point button is as follows:

```
Button decimal;
decimal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.decimal);
decimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            now = ".";
            equation1 = equation.concat(now);
            total1 = total.concat(now);
            equation = equation1;
            total = total1;
            if(b){mnDbHelper.updateNote(equation, mnDbHelper.testCount());}
            else{mnDbHelper.createNote(equation);
            b=true;}
            fillData();
        }
```

});

Here is the code for FillData:

```
private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = mnDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();

    startManagingCursor(c);

   String[] columns = new String[] {EquationsDbAdapter.KEY_VALUE};

   int to[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

   SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,c , columns , to);

   setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Here is sample code for one of the other buttons:

```
  Button times;
        times = (Button)findViewById(R.id.times);
        times.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                now = "*";
                equation1 = equation.concat(now);r = equation;
                equation = equation1;z = equation;
                if(total!="")
                {try{
                    formatter.parse(total);
                }
                catch(Throwable t){
                    really = false;
                }
                if(really){
                    try {
                        mDbHelper.createNote((BigDecimal) formatter.parse(total), fa, fa, fa, fa, fa, fa, jkl, fa, fa);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                total = "";
                total1 = "";}
                else{really = true;}}
                mDbHelper.createNote(jkl, fa, fa, t, fa, fa, fa, jkl, fa, fa);
                if(b){mnDbHelper.updateNote(equation, mnDbHelper.testCount());}
                else{mnDbHelper.createNote(equation);
                b=true;}
                fillData();
            }
    });
```

formatter is as follows:

```
 DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##################################################################################.################################");
```

Edit: oddly enough "0.33333333" displayed doesn't display right, but when * is added it does, however when * is subtracted from it again it doesn't.
As always, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must be doing something odd with your String. How do you display it? System.out.println() doesn't trim Strings, no matter their content.

Comment: How exactly are you displaying the numbers (or converting them to strings)?

Comment: I am displaying them by adding that to a database which is then displayed in a ListView, adding this to OP.

Comment: Could you please post the actual code which converts the number to something other than a Java double? (If it goes directly into a database, then that's when that happens.)

Comment: `if(total!="")` is not right.  That should be `if (!("".equals(total)))` or maybe `if (total.length() > 0)`.

Comment: What is `formatter`?  Can you show that definition?

Comment: Gray, the total part works fine as shown by my 3rd scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just adding a space to the beginning of the string, and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Huh.  Well the problem does not seem to be in the `formatter` object.  It returns a `Double` unless the `setParseBigDecimal(true)` has been called but you'd get a cast error if you tried to cast a `Double` to a `BigDecimal`.  I don't think you need the formatter and should be calling the following but I don't see where that causes the truncation:

```
new BigDecimal(total)
```

---

Is suspect that somewhere you are going from a `String` to a `double` or `float` which is truncating the precision of the `BigDecimal`.  For example, are you sure you aren't doing:

```
working = BigDecimal.valueOf((double)value);
```

Make sure that you are using the `String` constructor for `BigDecimal`:

```
working = new BigDecimal(valueStr);
```

This does a character-by-character processing of the string to create the `BigDecimal` without a loss in precision.

If you provide more details (like many comments have asked) and show the code that is actually creating the `BigDecimal` than I'll edit my answer to provide more information.

---

The code:

```
if(total!="")
```

is not right.  You rarely want to compare strings with `==` or `!=`.  I suspect that should be:

```
if (!("".equals(total)))
```

or maybe

```
if (total.length() > 0)
```

Comment: I don't display working, I display equation which never uses double or float to construct itself.

Comment: Please edit your question to show that code which @jersam515.

Comment: Ok, I did. Thanks for looking into my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is so interesting, because the obvious, `double` instead of `BigDecimal`, is not the case.
You mentioned the database. Maybe you reload the field from the database, and the record field is a `DOUBLE` and not `DECIMAL`, or `DECIMAL` with wrong **precision**.

Comment: The database saves the string as a string. The other one that does calculations uses a blob. What I find odd about it is that "0.6758431" doesn't display correctly but after I add a * to it it displays as "0.6758431*"